# Get version number for pyswip package

Tags: python, linux, prolog

I have installed pyswip package in my system. When I import `pyswip` package  using `import pyswip`, no error, but could not see it's version details.

```
swipl -dump-runtime-variables
```

gives :

```
CC="gcc";
PLBASE="/usr/lib/swipl-6.6.6";
PLARCH="i686-linux";
PLLIBS="";
PLLIB="-lswipl";
PLCFLAGS="-fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -fPIC ";
PLLDFLAGS="-rdynamic -O2 -pthread -Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib/swipl-6.6.6/lib/i686-linux ";
PLSOEXT="so";
PLSOPATH="LD_LIBRARY_PATH";
PLVERSION="60606";
PLSHARED="yes";
PLTHREADS="yes";
```

pyswip -V gives:

```
pyswip: command not found
```

IS there any way to get version or installation details for this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install this package? If you are using pip, you can view version like this:

```
pip freeze | grep pyswip
```

Or in runtime:

```
import pkg_resources 
pkg_resources.get_distribution("pyswip").version
```

Comment: thanks, but what i want to getting version number for installed pyswip package

Comment: I've edited answer. Seems old versions of pip don't support `show` command.

Comment: thanks a lot, `pip freeze | grep <package_name>` will give version for any package? or only those which were installed using `pip`? what is the concept here

Comment: `pip freeze` shows all packages that installed in current environment, not only via pip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71015/discussion-between-nlper-and-eugene-soldatov).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a `pyswip` command line utility; it's a library, after all.

However, `pyswip`'s `__init__.py` contains a `__VERSION__` string, so

```
import pyswip
print pyswip.___VERSION___
```

should work.

EDIT: adding `__init__.py` (omitting a few lines of comments); if the `pyswip/__init__.py` installed on your system doesn't contain the `__VERSION__` string, it's simply too old.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# pyswip -- Python SWI-Prolog bridge
# Copyright (c) 2007-2012 Yüce Tekol
#  
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#  
# .... MIT license ....


# PySWIP version
__VERSION__ = "0.2.3"

from pyswip.prolog import Prolog
from pyswip.easy import *
```

Comment: thanks for help, but it gives `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '___VERSION___'`